# Java File list same order like Window explorer

Tags: java, explorer, natural-sort

I am using the code below to get file list ordering: (like window explorer)

```java
    package com.codnix.quickpdfgenerator.testing;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class FileListOrder {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            //huge test data set ;)

            File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Codnix\\Desktop\\Test Sequence");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            List<File> filenames = Arrays.asList(listOfFiles); 

            //adaptor for comparing files
            Collections.sort(filenames, new Comparator<File>() {
                private final Comparator<String> NATURAL_SORT = new WindowsExplorerComparator();

                @Override
                public int compare(File o1, File o2) {;
                    return NATURAL_SORT.compare(o1.getName(), o2.getName());
                }
            });

            for (File f : filenames) {
                System.out.println(f);
            }
        }

        public static class WindowsExplorerComparator implements Comparator<String> {

            private static final Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\.|\\s");

            @Override
            public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                Iterator<String> i1 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str1).iterator();
                Iterator<String> i2 = splitStringPreserveDelimiter(str2).iterator();
                while (true) {
                    //Til here all is equal.
                    if (!i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    //first has no more parts -> comes first
                    if (!i1.hasNext() && i2.hasNext()) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    //first has more parts than i2 -> comes after
                    if (i1.hasNext() && !i2.hasNext()) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    String data1 = i1.next();
                    String data2 = i2.next();
                    int result;
                    try {
                        //If both datas are numbers, then compare numbers
                        result = Long.compare(Long.valueOf(data1), Long.valueOf(data2));
                        //If numbers are equal than longer comes first
                        if (result == 0) {
                            result = -Integer.compare(data1.length(), data2.length());
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        //compare text case insensitive
                        result = data1.compareToIgnoreCase(data2);
                    }

                    if (result != 0) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            private List<String> splitStringPreserveDelimiter(String str) {
                Matcher matcher = splitPattern.matcher(str);
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                int pos = 0;
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    list.add(str.substring(pos, matcher.start()));
                    list.add(matcher.group());
                    pos = matcher.end();
                }
                list.add(str.substring(pos));
                return list;
            }
        } 
    }
```

**BUT**, output when I run the program:

```
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test -12.jpg
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test --11.jpg
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test ---10.jpg
```

Expected Output (Like window explorer):

```
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test ---10.jpg
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test --11.jpg
C:\Users\Codnix\Desktop\Test Sequence\1 test -12.jpg
```

[image: in window explorer it showing like this(sort by name)]

What to do to get file list like this?

**UPDATED**

**Implemented solution provided by @jannis**

```
And here its output

before

1 test ---10.jpg
1 test --11.jpg
1 test -12.jpg
1.jpg
10.jpg
2.jpg

After (output)

1.jpg
1 test ---10.jpg
1 test --11.jpg
1 test -12.jpg
2.jpg
10.jpg
```

**Expected**

[image]

Comment: why can't you just use `file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());`?

Comment: Sorting by name in Windows is non-trivial and is far more complicated than in your implementation. It's also configurable and version dependent.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290541/what-is-the-first-character-in-the-sort-order-used-by-windows-explorer/4314191#4314191) Windows uses [StrCmpLogicalW](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) for sorting files by name. You could try to implement your comparator by calling this system function using JNI.

Comment: @jannis can you give little hit how to use it..

Comment: 'll try to give you an example later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorting by name in Windows is tricky and far more complicated than your implementation. It's also configurable and version dependent.

**NOTE: I created a demo for what follows in this post. [Check it out on GitHub](https://github.com/jannis-baratheon/stackoverflow--sorting-with-winapi).**

## Sorting file names using [StrCmpLogicalWComparator function](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw)

According to some (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290541/what-is-the-first-character-in-the-sort-order-used-by-windows-explorer/4314191#4314191)) Windows uses [StrCmpLogicalW](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw) for sorting files by name.

You could try to implement your comparator by calling this system function using JNA (don't forget to include [JNA library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna) in your project):

Comparator:

```
public class StrCmpLogicalWComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return Shlwapi.INSTANCE.StrCmpLogicalW(
            new WString(o1), new WString(o2));
    }
}
```

JNA part:

```
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Shlwapi extends StdCallLibrary {

    Shlwapi INSTANCE = Native.load("Shlwapi", Shlwapi.class);

    int StrCmpLogicalW(WString psz1, WString psz2);
}
```

## Handling file names that contain digits

I mentioned earlier that the way that Windows Explorer sorts files is configurable. You can change how numbers in file names are handled and toggle so-called "numerical sorting". You can read how to configure this [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/91417-enable-disable-numerical-sorting-file-explorer-windows-10-a.html). Numerical sorting as explained in the docs:

> Treat digits as numbers during sorting, for example, sort "2" before "10".
>
> -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringex#SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS

With numerical sorting enabled the result is:

[image: file names sorted with numerical sorting enabled]

whereas with numerical sorting disabled it looks like this:

[image: file names sorted with numerical sorting disabled]

**This makes me think that Windows Explorer in fact uses [CompareStringEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringex) for sorting which can be parameterized to enable this feature.**

## Sorting file names using [CompareStringEx function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-comparestringex)

JNA part:

```
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.WString;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    Kernel32 INSTANCE = Native.load("Kernel32", Kernel32.class);
    WString INVARIANT_LOCALE = new WString("");

    int CompareStringEx(WString lpLocaleName,
                        int dwCmpFlags,
                        WString lpString1,
                        int cchCount1,
                        WString lpString2,
                        int cchCount2,
                        Pointer lpVersionInformation,
                        Pointer lpReserved,
                        int lParam);

    default int CompareStringEx(int dwCmpFlags,
                                String str1,
                                String str2) {
        return Kernel32.INSTANCE
            .CompareStringEx(
                INVARIANT_LOCALE,
                dwCmpFlags,
                new WString(str1),
                str1.length(),
                new WString(str2),
                str2.length(),
                Pointer.NULL,
                Pointer.NULL,
                0);
    }
}
```

Numeric sort comparator:

```
public class CompareStringExNumericComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static int SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS = 0x00000008;

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int compareStringExComparisonResult =
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CompareStringEx(SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS, o1, o2);

        // CompareStringEx returns 1, 2, 3 respectively instead of -1, 0, 1
        return compareStringExComparisonResult - 2;
    }
}
```

Non-numeric sort comparator:

```
public class CompareStringExNonNumericComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private static String INVARIANT_LOCALE = "";
    private static int NO_OPTIONS = 0;

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int compareStringExComparisonResult =
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CompareStringEx(NO_OPTIONS, o1, o2);

        // CompareStringEx returns 1, 2, 3 respectively instead of -1, 0, 1
        return compareStringExComparisonResult - 2;
    }
}
```

## References

- [Martin Liversage's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98607/martin-liversage) [answer to "What is the shortest way in .NET to sort strings starting with 1, 10 and 2 and respect the number ordering?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7205788/4494577)
- [hmuelner's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324065/hmuelner) [answer to "What is the first character in the sort order used by Windows Explorer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314191/4494577)

Comment: This is i need to add in pom net.java.dev.jna   right?

Comment: yep @ButaniVijay

Comment: sorry for too much questions!.  but i am getting com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary not exist ...i added dependency in pom and build code...may be build issue from my side

Comment: Failed to collect dependencies for [net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:5.5.0 (compile)

Comment: Try running my example with `./mvnw test`

Comment: will your example open in netbean?

Comment: @ButaniVijay I have no idea, but most probably there is a way to import a Maven project to Netbeans, but you're on your own here.

Comment: check my updated question.....may be need to workout more to achieve like window

Comment: @ButaniVijay I've updated the answer and the example. I fixed my JNA proxy:`StrCmpLogicalW` takes wide strings (JNA's `com.sun.jna.WString`) as parameters and in the previous solution I was using ordinary `String`s which by default are not converted to `WString`s by JNA unless you specify an additional parameter to `Native.load` method (`Native.load("Shlwapi", Shlwapi.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS)` - when loading the library like that even an ordinary `String` will do).

Comment: @ButaniVijay if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for everything.....so i am going to use NumericalCompareStringExComparator    for sorting like window ,  is it right?   I am appreciate your help and would like to donate !!!Let me know how can i help for your cup of coffee?

Comment: @ButaniVijay :) I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: NumericalCompareStringExComparator   is it final one window explorer using right?

Comment: Like I wrote it depends on the "numerical sort" setting. Sorting using `CompareStringExNumericComparator` acts as if "numerical sort" was enabled and `CompareStringExNonNumericComparator` otherwise.